# How do I add England, Scotland and Wales to the symfony2 CountryType?

Tags: symfony, internationalization, locale

Symfony2 has a country list via

```
$allCountries = Intl::getRegionBundle()->getCountryNames();
```

The problem I am facing is that it only has "United Kingdom" via the "UK" iso key. What it does not contain are England, Wales and Scotland.

How would I add them?

Comment: [This question about Kosovo seems related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20816790/manipulate-the-list-of-countries-provided-by-symfony-intl-and-the-form-choice-ty)